# Some issues with sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm beginning with sockets for my very first time. 
I'm trying to set up a server that its only function is to give back to the client a string i send.
The client doesn't send the string, and the server doesn't receive it. Here it goes the code:

Server code:

```
package servidor;

//All imports needed

public class Servidor {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket socketServidor = new ServerSocket(2000);
            Socket socketDatos = socketServidor.accept();
            PrintWriter escribirCliente = new PrintWriter(socketDatos.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader leerCliente = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketDatos.getInputStream()));

            String linea;

            while((linea = leerCliente.readLine())!= null){
                System.out.println("hola");
                System.out.println("Server: "+ linea);
                escribirCliente.println(linea);
                if(linea.equals("x")){
                    break;
                }
            }

            socketDatos.close();
            escribirCliente.close();
            leerCliente.close();
            socketServidor.close();

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Fallo en la conexion.");
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
package cliente;

//All imports needed

public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2000);
        BufferedReader leerServidor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter escribirServidor = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String linea = teclado.readLine();
        //System.out.println(""+linea);

        while (!(linea.equals("x"))){
            System.out.println("en while");
            escribirServidor.println(linea);
            System.out.println("eco: "+ leerServidor.readLine());
            linea = teclado.readLine();
        }

        escribirServidor.close();
        leerServidor.close();
        teclado.close();
        socket.close();

    }
}
```

The thing is:
In the client, the execution never reaches the "eco" but it does reach the "en while". But in the server, that while is never reached. Not even printing the "hola". I supposed that the issue should be when reading the line, but i've been not able to fix it.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try calling `PrintWriter#flush` after your calls to `PrintWriter#println`.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that I was not calling the correct method initializing escribirServidor. Second parameter was missing, which is autoflush. If set as the Server, calling the method with autoflush True it starts working!!